# Numerical accuracy of 5 stenciles vs 9 stencils domain decomposition compared to single domain

Tags: mpi, numerical-methods

I was wondering if there are any numerical accuracy sacrifice when it comes to the domain decomposition schemes between 5 stencils (using the boundary information of north, south, west and east neighbors) and 9 stencils (using the boundary information of north, south, west, east, north-east, north-west, south-east and south-west) model. Would these schemes have consistent numerical results of non-decomposed domain scheme (no sub domains)?

Comment: Unclear. "Sacrifice between 5-point and 9-point stencils". No, 9-point stencils are more accurate. "consistent numerical results" consistent with what? And what does this have to do with parallelism?

Comment: Consistent numerical results with "non-decomposed domain scheme (no sub domains)" as in serial code (say 1 core of CPU working the entire domain) solving advection equation, for example, without the any domain decomposition so that there won't be any boundary exchange problems.